# Meaning of Lab vs Labs

Tags: meaning

I am not a native speaker and confused about the use of **lab** and **labs**. What is the exact difference and when to use  what? Especially those days many companies use Lab/Labs in their company name.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. *Labs* is the plural of *lab*, which is a common abbreviation for *Laboratory*.

Comment: It's also the abbreviation of *Labrador*, (The dog) but that is obviously a different context.

Comment: As a native english speaker I can comment that this is a *very fair* question. Particularly in the contexts of companies and other organizations, its unclear why each _singular_ organization that uses the name "lab" chooses to pluralize it. Especially when many products can (and often do) come out of a single (literal and metaphorical) laboratory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Lab' is short for 'laboratory'. A company producing chemicals or medicines or performing scientific research might have a number of them, and might include 'laboratories' or 'labs' in its name to emphasise the scientific nature of its work.

> Laboratory noun informal lab ​ B1 a room or building with scientific equipment
>   for doing scientific tests or for teaching science, or a place where
>   chemicals or medicines are produced

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/laboratory